# Effectively select data points that are near to the center of the cluster

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn, data-science

Assume I have a dataset like this:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

%matplotlib inline

X,y = make_blobs(random_state=101) # My data

palette = sns.color_palette('bright',3)
sns.scatterplot(X[:,0], X[:,1],palette=palette,hue=y) # Visualizing the data
```

[image]

I would like to select data that is close to the center of the cluster. Say, I want to choose data close to the center from `cluster '0'`, I am currently doing like this:

```
label_0 = X[y==0] # Want to select data from the label '0'

data_index = 2 # Manaully pick the point
sns.scatterplot(X[:,0], X[:,1],palette=palette,hue=y)
plt.scatter(label_0[data_index][0],label_0[data_index][1],marker='*')
```

[image]

Since it is not close to the center, I change the index and pick another one.

```
data_index = 4
sns.scatterplot(X[:,0], X[:,1],palette=palette,hue=y)
plt.scatter(label_0[data_index][0],label_0[data_index][1],marker='*')
```

Now it's close. But I wonder if there's a more effective way to achieve this? It is manageable for a small dataset like this, but if my dataset has thousands of points, I don't think this method will work anymore.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use [K-means algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering).
This will help you find the centers of each cluster.

Given your datatset, the steps would be :

1) Find the number of clusters

```
num_clusters=len(np.unique(y)) #here 3
```

2) Apply [scikit's k-means clustering](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans.fit_transform) on your data

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters, random_state=0).fit(X)
```

3) Find the center of each cluster

```
centers=kmeans.cluster_centers_ # gives the centers of each cluster
# array([[ 0.26542862,  1.85466779],
#        [-9.50316411, -6.52747391],
#        [ 3.64354311,  6.62683956]])
```

4) Since these centers might not be part of your original data, we need to find the closest points to them

```
from scipy import spatial

def nearest_point(array,query):
    return array[spatial.KDTree(array).query(query)[1]]

nearest_centers=np.array([nearest_point(X,center) for center in centers])
# array([[ 0.19313183,  1.80387958],
#       [-9.12488396, -6.32638926],
#       [ 3.65986315,  6.69035824]])
```

5) Plot the original data and the centers

```
sns.scatterplot(X[:,0], X[:,1],palette=palette,hue=y) 
for nc in nearest_centers:
    plt.scatter(nc[0],nc[1],marker='*',color='r')
```

The centers are shows by the red crosses :

[image: The centers are shows by the red crosses]